# Angular:change result follow checked

Tags: angular, angular8

I want to change result when **field checked** of depositTasks is all true if some **field checked** of depositTasks have false give to as another result.

app.html

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="task.checked" (click)="changChecked(task.checked)"
 [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

app.ts

```
changChecked(checked) {
    checked = !checked
    if (this.depositTasks.length !== undefined) {
      for (let i = 0; this.depositTasks.length > i; i++) {
        if (this.depositTasks[i].checked === true ) {
          console.log('do');
          this.onSelectedStatus('Resolved')
        } else {
          this.onSelectedStatus('Assigned')
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but it is not clear what your goal is. Here is a solution how to figure out whether all checkboxes are checked or not:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="task.checked" (change)="onChange()"
 [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

**TS**

```
onChange(): void {
    if (this.depositTasks) {
        // when there is no element with checked state of false, the result is -1
        // and when the result is -1 our comparison returns true
        const allChecked = (this.depositTasks.findIndex(task => task.checked === false) === -1);

        if (allChecked) {
            this.onSelectedStatus('Resolved');
        } else {
            this.onSelectedStatus('Assigned');
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: my goal is when all checkboxes are checked: true to do this.onSelectedStatus('Resolved') but if  all checkboxes are checked: false to do this.onSelectedStatus('Assigned')

Comment: Okay, I adjusted the code according to your needs. If it fits, please mark this answer as solution. Thx in advance. 